# Figwheel / unable to declare a :ring-handler

Tags: clojure, ring, figwheel

My clojure/reagent project was initiated using a static `resources/public/index.html`, where `src/test/client.cljs` provides the rendering function.
Now I would like to switch the server side to a dynamic renderer (in order to provide a REST API to the client).
This is the structure of the project:

```
test
 |___src
 |    |___test
 |         |___core.clj
 |         |___client.cljs
 |___resources
 |    |___public
 |         |___index.html
 |         |___style.css
 |___project.clj
```

And the main files:

```
;; src/test/core.clj
(ns test.core
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:require
   [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
   [clostache.parser :as clostache]
   [compojure.route :as route]
   [compojure.handler]
   [clojure.data.json :as json]
   ))

(def home
  "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">
    <link href=\"style.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\">
    <link rel=\"icon\" href=\"https://clojurescript.org/images/cljs-logo-icon-32.png\">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id=\"container\"></div>
    <script src=\"/client.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>
  </body>
</html>")

(defn handler [request]
  (if (and (= :get (:request-method request))
           (= "/"  (:uri request)))
    {:status 200
     :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
     :body home}
    {:status 404
     :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
     :body "Not Found"}))
```

---

```
;; src/test/client.cljs
(ns test.client
  (:require
   [reagent.dom :as rdom]))

(defn test-container []
  [:div
   [:h1 "Test ring-handler"]
  ])

(defn ^:export run []
  (rdom/render [test-container] (js/document.getElementById "container")))
```

---

```
;; project.clj
(defproject test-ring-handler "0.1.2-SNAPSHOT"
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :description "test-ring-handler"
  :license {:name "GNU GPL v3+"
            :url "http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.11.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.11.54"]
                 [reagent "1.1.1"]
                 [cljsjs/react "18.0.0-rc.0-0"]
                 [cljsjs/react-dom "18.0.0-rc.0-0"]
                 [ring "1.9.5"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.9.5"]
                 [figwheel "0.5.20"]
                 ]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.7"]
            [lein-figwheel "0.5.19"]
            ]
  
  :resource-paths ["resources" "target"]
  :clean-targets ^{:protect false} [:target-path]

  :profiles {:dev {:cljsbuild
                   {:builds {:client
                             {:figwheel {:on-jsload "test.client/run"}
                              :compiler {:main "test.client"
                                         :optimizations :none}}}}}}

  :figwheel {:repl false
;;             :http-server-root "public"
             :ring-handler test.core/handler
             }
  
  :cljsbuild {:builds {:client
                       {:source-paths ["src"]
                        :compiler {:output-dir "target/public/client"
                                   :asset-path "client"
                                   :output-to "target/public/client.js"
                                   :main "test.core"}}}}
  )
```

---

When the :ring-handler option is commented, everything is compiled correctly and  `client.cljs` correctly renders the title "Test ring-handler".
If :ring-handler is activated, the compilation fails:

```
$ lein figwheel
Figwheel: Validating the configuration found in project.clj
Figwheel: Configuration Valid ;)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to require the namespace of the handler test.core/handler for :ring-handler
    at figwheel_sidecar.utils$illegal_argument.invokeStatic(utils.clj:53)
    at figwheel_sidecar.utils$illegal_argument.doInvoke(utils.clj:52)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at figwheel_sidecar.components.figwheel_server$create_initial_state$fn__19826.invoke(figwheel_server.clj:323)
...
```

What is the syntax to use so that the server requests are redirected to `test.core/handler`?

Comment: About 2018, Figwheel launched the "2.0" version, known as `figwheel-main`. At the same time, the primary (best) way of using it migrated from lein to Clojure Deps/CLI. Please see the main website and follow along the extensive tutorial at https://figwheel.org/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sadly the commands described in the figwheel.main tutorial you pointed me to do not work with Debian/clojure-1.10.2 (e.g `clj` or `clojure -M -m figwheel.main`). I guess I'm stuck with `lein` for the moment.